# Soulmate for someone who died unwed

Tags: marriage, soul, heaven, afterlife

I had a friend who was dating a woman. They were close but not "in love". Anyway, he passed away and she moved on. Well, she met someone new and they are in love.

My question is, what does G-d do about the friend I had who passed away?

Is there someone for everyone? Maybe G-d creates in the entire eternity someone for everyone. I think G-d would make it so everyone in heaven is happy and has someone to spend eternity with.

I feel like G-d's plan is that there is someone for everyone however mathematically I just don't see how it's possible.

This man is deceased and in heaven however he also deserves the right to a woman to spend the rest of eternity with. Does G-d create someone in heaven that is his soulmate?

How does this all work? It seems so complicated to me.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11978/603

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11953 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2447

Answer (score 5):

The Ramchal writes in a letter that in his time (already 300 years ago) there is no longer "one" soulmate for everyone - in earlier generations, complete souls came to the world, and each soul had it's other half.  However, today our souls are actually just fractions of greater souls, and not necessarily is there a corresponding "piece" to your fraction of a soul that is in the world at the same time as you.  Rather, the "mission" of these soul-fractions is to create new combinations of souls.

This is because of how the Ramchal understands reincarnation - if a soul fulfilled, say, 70% of its purpose, then only 30% of that soul would need further completion and come back.  Therefore, the souls today are fractions of souls.

The "greater" soul of which your friend was a fraction has its other half, and will ultimately be completed.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and a difficult one. There are many different interpretations of some Talmudic quotes about this. [Here's a lecture](http://kmtt.libsyn.com/theology_13) entitled "The Theology of Shidduchim."

Comment: ["Even more helpful would be to also **summarize**, *in your own words*, what the external material says."](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75)