# Do non-jews have soul mates?

Tags: gentiles, marriage, hashgacha-pratit

[We know that Jews have soul mates: people whom they are destined to marry.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
Do non-Jews have people they are destined to marry?

Comment: Jews have predestined futures? We don't have free will?

Comment: @DoubleAA yes we have them. The topic is confusing. It says in the gemara that God decides who a man will marry before hes born.

Comment: Well, then [edit]ing in a source for that gemara would improve this question.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/40-days-before-conception/3442#3442

Comment: chapter 3 in shaar bitachon says: He watches over and directs the lives of all men, He does not abandon any of them (from bestowing good or benefiting them according to their needs - Pas Lechem commentary). implies yes.

Answer (score 5):

The Midrash ([Bereishis Rabbah 68:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=164), and other places) tells a story involving R. Yosei ben Chalafta and a Roman lady, where he tells her that since the six days of creation Hashem occupies Himself with making matches and redistributing wealth ("the daughter of A will marry B; the wife of C will marry D; the assets of E will go to F"); she mocks this and claims that "I could do the same"; she attempts to pair off her slaves, only to find that none of the matches work out, forcing her to admit that "there is no G-d like yours - your Torah is true, beautiful and praiseworthy."

(In a similar vein, there is a popular story about R. Yitzchak Abarbanel having a similar discussion with the king of Castile, which leads to a mixup in which the crown prince is forced to marry an old woman instead of the young one whom the king had selected. Though I don't know whether it's a true story, or where the original source is.)

The implication, then, seems to be that this applies across the board, to Jews and non-Jews alike.

Comment: I'm not sure if the first story proves that there non-jews have a predestined soulmate, as much as it proves that pairing people takes effort.

Answer (score 0):

It goes for ALL souls non-jews and Jews..  Everyone has soul mates.. Adam was a non-jew and he has a soulmate :)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Nick! Consider editing in how you know this to be true (sources, reasoning, etc.).

Comment: Welcome to MY Nick. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site.