# Can a Jew have a non-Jewish "bashert" or vice-versa?

Tags: gentiles, marriage, intermarriage

Follow-up to "[Do non-jews have soul mates?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28743/do-non-jews-have-soul-mates)":

Can a Jew have a non-Jewish "bashert" (Divinely designated soul-mate) or vice-versa?

Answer (score 4):

The idea of Bashert is that soul-mates are actually two halves of a single soul. Jews and non-Jews possess different types of souls. Therefore, a Jew and a non-Jew cannot be two halves of one soul, and cannot be Bashert.

A convert is a different story. When a person converts, he receives in some way a new, Jewish soul (i.e. a neshama with a connection to knesses yisrael) in addition to his human soul (i.e. the tzelem elokim) that he posessed prior to conversion. The Jewish soul is considered newly born, and can match up with a Jew. Prior to the conversion, the aspiring convert does not possess the type of soul that can be Bashert for a Jew.

Comment: As I understand it, the convert's Jewish soul existed and was present at Mt. Sinai, but did not fully join his body until he converted.  Nevertheless, there must be some element of that soul in one's body.  I know that one reason I decided to convert was that all of my ideas on religion turned out to be Jewish.

Comment: @BruceJames The way I understand it is that the Jewish and non-Jewish souls are not two different, albeit comparable souls but two different type of soul. The Jewish soul is not an additional soul of the same level but rather a soul of a different type entirely, that comes in addition to the previously existing non-Jewish soul. This comment would make more sense in Hebrew, which possesses upwards of five words that describe the various aspects/levels/types of soul.

Comment: @LN6595 Are you referring to *nefesh/ru'ach/n'shama/chaya/yechida* ([*Alshich* on *B'reishis* 43:33](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40267&st=&pgnum=251), based on [*Breishis Rabba* 14:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&pgnum=37) and [*D'varim Rabba* 2:26](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&pgnum=175))?

Comment: @Fred Precisely.

Comment: @LN6595 how do you know any of this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the translations match up exactly, but Rabi Akiva saw the wife of Turnus Rufus and knew through ruach hakodesh that he was going to marry her after she converted.

See [Nedarim top of 50b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=16&daf=50b&format=pdf) with Rashi and Ran.

Comment: But that does not mean she was his *soul mate*? He just saw the future (as every prophecy).

Comment: Again, I'm not sure if the translations match up. In other words I'm not sure what the difference between ruach hakodesh relaying this message or a bas kol saying bas ploni liploni is, I'm not sure if there is a difference. But I do see here a Jew and a non-jewess destined to marry.

Comment: Not *destined*, just R'Akiva saw the *future*... That is like the bechira: H-m *knows* the future, but we are *free* (and thus, responsible) for our actions...

Comment: I think this has become a game of semantics. Think of a word you agree with as not contradicting bechira to explain the zivig announced of bas ploni liploni and insert it here.

Answer (score 1):

no and here's why...
1) a union of a Jew and a non-Jew is not a marriage. not only is it wrong to have such relationship of this type but doing so isn't even considered being married at all.
2) G-d would not have your bashert be someone you could not marry

Comment: This answer would be much more valuable if you could [edit] in your sources.

Comment: Maybe they're supposed to convert.

Comment: it would only be after a convert converts that they could be someone's bashert and not before. while this might sound the same at first there is a subtle difference

Comment: @Dude - I don't know how true that point is. What "religion" were Rivkah, Rachel and Le'ah, or for that matter, Abraham and Sarah? Joseph married an Egyptian, and Moshe married a Midianite. We assume those 2 converted, though there is no mention in Tana"ch of that. Are you suggesting theat each of these women were not already pre-destined (bashert) prior to conversion?

Comment: being Jewish is about the neshama. before manton toirah each individual had to live their lives a certain way to ensure this. after manton toirah it became solidified that the Jewish people were connected in way to G-d like never before and so this neshamah could now be passed on by birth from their parents

Comment: she was a convert and before converting could not have been his bashert

Answer (score -2):

Wasn't King David only born because of the fact that Boaz who when was an Israelite married Ruth a Moabite? So in essence, one of the greatest Kings in Jewish history wasn't of complete Jewish descent. In fact, I believe I read that because Ruth tricked Boaz into getting her pregnant, her merits were blessed? Wouldnt that mean The Mashiach would be of only half Jewish decent?

Also, didn't Queen Esther marry a non Jew? King Soloman was with Queen Sheba who wasn't a Jew. My apology if I'm totally off as I'm trying to understand why some of our forefathers could do what they wanted and it was accepted?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Ploni Yes it does. You might not think that it marshals the most compelling evidence, but it seems to answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Shir!

Comment: Bashert only applies to a first match, though (Sotah 2a). Sure, Esther and Solomon married non-Jews. But they were both previously married (Esther to Mordecai and Solomon to, well, 999 other women.) And as for Ruth, she converted, so she was completely Jewish at that point.