# Marriage/Zivug Sheini

Tags: zivug-sheini, zivug, zechut-merit

We know that first marriages are arranged in Heaven 40 days before a child is created. Second marriages however are based on the person's merits. What happens when it's a first marriage for one spouse but a second marriage for the other spouse? Do we say that it was arranged in Heaven on account of the one never before married or is it based on the individual's merits due to the partner that was already married? Perhaps it's both?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2447/759

Comment: See commentaries to [Sotah 2a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=2&format=pdf).

Comment: Note that many things are less than so simple in reality. Regarding the premises in this question, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81350/8775.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Sruli!

Comment: Consider clarifying the sources for what "we know" in this question. Not everyone has the same background knowledge as you.

Comment: Funny that you changed your wording in reality there are different versions of the passage; some refer to creation, others to birth.

Comment: Note that the passage seems to view the groom as the subject and the bride as one of the objects, like a field, that whose later owners are predetermined. One would certainly get the impression that the determinant is the groom.

Comment: According to [those authorities](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81350/8775) who are of he opinion that everything is either the result of chance or reward and punishment, there is no reason to assume that here would be any different. Reward and punishment apply to both men and women. This question would therefore be a subset of the larger question of how reward and punishment is meted out to individuals, given that it also affects others.

Comment: I have... complicated thoughts on the concept of predestination that fit right in with "HaKol Tzafuy Vihareshut Netunah" and higher order mathematic dimensions. But put simply, why could it not be possible for one person to be predestined to marry someone who merits to marry them back?