# Chatam Sofer and soulmates

Tags: soul, chatam-sofer, zivug-sheini

I've been looking for the exact text, or at least a link to the Chatam Sofer bringing down the Ari on the topic of soulmates in Shu”t Chatam Sofer 7:34. I've seen it quoted in several articles, but have been unable to find the text online or on Sefaria.

Comment: I think the Peleh Yoetz also quotes this notion.

Comment: @pcoz possibly. but im specifically looking for the chatam sofer text

Comment: perhaps of interest is the letter mentioned here, especially the part from the Ari HaKadosh: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8125/603

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Teshuvos Chasam Sofer Volume 7 is a collection of (until recently) unpublished responsa from the Chasam Sofer. It's under copyright from the Machon Chasam Sofer, so you won't find it on Sefaria.

Luckily for you, it's on Otzar Hachochma, and it's within the first 150 pages, so it's available for free viewing. [Here's a link to Chasam Sofer 7:34](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/155831/p/98/t/1/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c). The paragraph you want starts with ונראה.

I don't have time right now to transcribe the teshuva. What he basically says is *zivug rishon* is one's initial, predestined mate, and through a person's actions they can either deserve a better mate or a worse one, which is their *zivug sheni*. This fits nicely with the gemarra's statement that a person's mate is לפי מעשיו.

Note that when citing this explanation, he writes that he *thinks* it's from the Arizal. However, the Arizal doesn't say this. In his Shaar HaGilgulim *Introduction* 20 and Sefer HaGilgulim Chapter 13, he says instead that *zivug sheni* has to do with *gilgulim*, reincarnation.

The source is actually the Zohar *parshas Lech Lecha* p. 85b and 91b. This explanation is also found in the [Yaavetz](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37960&st=&pgnum=762) and [Be'er Sheva](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1821&st=&pgnum=105&hilit) to Sotah 2a, in the name of the *chachmei haemes*.

Comment: YES. this is EXACTLY what i was looking for. also, thx for the heads up on the Arizal misattribution!

Comment: If you found it useful feel free to mark it as correct